# Checkbox is always checked

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using knockout JS template for showing controls. But checkbox is always showing as checked. Below I'm binding ActualValue property to checkbox, which is a string property.

**jQuery Template**

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="membershipMetaDataTemplate">
<tr>
    <td><span data-bind="text: DisplayName" ></span></td>
    {{if ObjectType() == 'string'}}
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: ActualValue, disable: ReadOnly" />
    {{/if}}

    {{if ObjectType() == 'boolean'}}
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ActualValue, disable: ReadOnly" /></td>
    {{/if}}

    {{if ObjectType() == 'dropdown'}}
          <td><select data-bind="options: PermittedValues, value: ActualValue, disable: ReadOnly, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"/></td>
    {{/if}}

</tr>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in JavaScript:

```
alert(new Boolean("true"));
alert(new Boolean("false"));
alert(new Boolean(""));
```

The first two will show *true*, the third will show *false*. This is because, in JavaScript, any non-empty string converts to boolean *true*.

In your example, it sounds like you are passing the string `"false"` to the checkbox. Since the string `"false"` is a non-empty string, it has boolean value *true*, so the checkbox gets ticked.

One solution to this is to define a [writeable computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#writeable_computed_observables) that converts the strings `"true"` and `"false"` into the expected boolean values:

```
var viewModel = {
    ActualValue: ko.observable("false")
};

viewModel.ActualValueAsBoolean = ko.computed({
    read: function () { return this.ActualValue() === "true"; },
    write: function (newValue) { this.ActualValue(newValue ? "true" : "false"); },
    owner: viewModel
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then bind checked to `ActualValueAsBoolean` instead of `ActualValue`.

Answer (score 3):

I had an instance where I am mapping an array of JSON objects ajaxed in so it made creating computed observable variables messy.

For this situation I found a custom binder to be much less obtrusive.

Here is what I used-

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stringToBool = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)     {

        var value = valueAccessor();
        var val = value().toLowerCase() === 'true';
        $(element).prop('checked', val);
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).prop('checked'));
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel,    bindingContext) {



    }
};
```

Then you bind using this instead of the stock checked binding

---

input type="checkbox" data-bind="stringToBool: value"